# Adding labels inside custom cell dynamically

Tags: ios, uilabel, custom-cell

I'm adding UIlabels dynamically in custom cell,the gap between each labels were not aligned properly.so,please help me to resolve this issue.

```
 cell.lblObj.numberOfLines=0;
 cell.lblObj.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
 CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(170,100);
 CGSize expectedLabelSize = [strfrom sizeWithFont:cell.lblObj.font
                                   constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize
                                       lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
 CGRect newFrame = cell.lblObj.frame;
 newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
 cell.lblObj.frame = newFrame;
 cell.lblObj.text=strfrom;
 [cell.lblObj sizeToFit];
```

[image: Please Check this screen]

```
 NSString *strfrom=[[mtblarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"source"];
 cell.lblfrom.numberOfLines=0;
 cell.lblfrom.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
 CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(170,100);
 CGSize expectedLabelSize = [strfrom sizeWithFont:cell.lblfrom.font
                                   constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize
                                       lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
 CGRect newFrame = cell.lblfrom.frame;
 newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
 cell.lblfrom.frame = newFrame;
 cell.lblfrom.text=strfrom;
 [cell.lblfrom sizeToFit];
 cell.lblfrom.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Comment: are you trying to add the labels vertically one after the other, and for this calculating y origin of each label with some padding between each label, right?

Comment: @SanjayMohnani Thanq for your reply.yes but i'm adding labels horizontally one after the other

Comment: so you need to calculate the x origin for each label and add it with some padding between the labels, right?

Comment: once please check that screen,same as that screen but i'll be having more labels in each cell.

Comment: can you also post the screenshot of your screen with issue as well?

Comment: in first cell there is more gap between labels and in second cell it is very clumsy .please check it @SanjayMohnani

Comment: @Sneha, thanks for the screenshot, it seems that your From label's value label's height is calculated by calculating the text size, whereas the value label of To filed is kept static, am I right?

Comment: yes you are right @SanjayMohnani

Comment: and I think rather than keeping the height static(for the value label of To filed), calculate the text size first and based on the text size frame the To filed's value label, and add it, after adding the label, y origin for Person label should be maxYofToValueLabel + yPaddingOffset

Comment: doing so will resolve your text overlapping issue and the gap will be visible between the labels

Comment: @SanjayMohnani actually the text will be varying for each cell..can you please send me sample code

Comment: sure, but how did you set the frame for the red labels (From label)?

Comment: please check my question i have edited my code @SanjayMohnani

Comment: @SanjayMohnani did you check that code

Answer (score 1):

Refer this url step by step ....

http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout